# `element.innerHTML` not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a form on whose submission, will post a URL, and the server returns a `HTML` string which should be appended to the form.

Sometimes it replaces the HTML content of the element with the new one but sometimes it replaces only few part of the HTML content received from the server.

I have tried `$(document.getElementById(element).html()` and `document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = ""` but both are working as same sometime it append the value but sometimes it does only a few part of it.

Test it with a YouTube url....

```js
$('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $('.login').addClass('test')
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.login').addClass('testtwo')
    }, 300);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".authent").show().animate({
            right: -320
        }, {
            easing: 'easeOutQuint',
            duration: 600,
            queue: false
        });
        $(".authent").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        }).addClass('visible');
    }, 500);
    var form = $('#download_video');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://testuia.herokuapp.com/formats',
        method: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response.success == true) {
            console.log(response.results);
            const formats = response.results;
            show_formats(formats);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('formats').innerHTML = response.error;
        };
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("");
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".authent").show().animate({
            right: 90
        }, {
            easing: 'easeOutQuint',
            duration: 600,
            queue: false
        });
        $(".authent").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        }).addClass('visible');
        $('.login').removeClass('testtwo')
    }, 2500);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.login').removeClass('test')
        $('.login div').fadeOut(123);
    }, 2800);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.success').fadeIn();
    }, 3200);
});

$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').focus(function () {
    $(this).prev().animate({
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 200)
});
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').blur(function () {
    $(this).prev().animate({
        'opacity': '.5'
    }, 200)
});

$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').keyup(function () {
    if (!$(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).next().animate({
            'opacity': '1',
            'right': '30'
        }, 200)
    } else {
        $(this).next().animate({
            'opacity': '0',
            'right': '20'
        }, 200)
    }
});

var open = 0;
$('.tab').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            'left': '0'
        })
    });
});

function show_formats(formats) {
 
   document.getElementById('formats').innerHTML = formats;
};
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gudea:400,700);
 body {
     perspective: 800px;
     height: 100vh;
     margin: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     font-family: 'Gudea', sans-serif;
     background: #ea5c54;
    /* Old browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ea5c54 0%, #bb6dec 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #ea5c54), color-stop(100%, #bb6dec));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ea5c54 0%, #bb6dec 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
     background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ea5c54 0%, #bb6dec 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ea5c54 0%, #bb6dec 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
     background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ea5c54 0%, #bb6dec 100%);
    /* W3C */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#EA5C54 ', endColorstr='#bb6dec',GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
 body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #4e546d;
}
 body .authent {
     display: none;
     background: #35394a;
    /* Old browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #35394a), color-stop(100%, #1f222e));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
     background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
     background: linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* W3C */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#35394a', endColorstr='#1f222e',GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 90px;
     margin: auto;
     width: 100px;
     color: white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 20px 70px;
     top: 200px;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 70px;
     opacity: 0;
}
 body .authent p {
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
}
 body .success {
     display: none;
     color: #d5d8e2;
}
 body .success p {
     font-size: 14px;
}
 body p {
     color: #5b5e6f;
     font-size: 10px;
     text-align: left;
}
 body .testtwo {
     left: -320px !important;
}
 body .test {
     box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
     pointer-events: none;
     top: -100px !important;
     transform: rotateX(70deg) scale(0.8) !important;
     opacity: 0.6 !important;
     filter: blur(1px);
}
 body .login {
     opacity: 1;
     top: 20px;
     -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.25, 0.265, 0.85);
     transition-property: transform, opacity, box-shadow, top, left;
     transition-duration: 0.5s;
     transform-origin: 161px 100%;
     transform: rotateX(0deg);
     position: relative;
     width: 240px;
     border-top: 2px solid #d8312a;
     height: 300px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin: auto;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 100px 40px 40px 40px;
     background: #35394a;
    /* Old browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #35394a), color-stop(100%, #1f222e));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
     background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
     background: linear-gradient(45deg, #35394a 0%, #1f222e 100%);
    /* W3C */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#35394a', endColorstr='#1f222e',GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
 body .login .validation {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     right: 10px;
     top: 6px;
     opacity: 0;
}
 body .login .disclaimer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 20px;
     left: 35px;
     width: 250px;
}
 body .login_title {
     color: #afb1be;
     height: 60px;
     text-align: left;
     font-size: 16px;
}
 body .login_fields {
     height: 208px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
}
 body .login_fields .icon {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     left: 36px;
     top: 8px;
     opacity: 0.5;
}
 body .login_fields input[type='password'] {
     color: #dc6180 !important;
}
 body .login_fields input[type='text'], body .login_fields input[type='password'] {
     color: #afb1be;
     width: 190px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     background: #32364a;
     left: 0;
     padding: 10px 65px;
     border-top: 2px solid #393d52;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #393d52;
     border-right: none;
     border-left: none;
     outline: none;
     font-family: 'Gudea', sans-serif;
     box-shadow: none;
}
 body .login_fields__user, body .login_fields__password {
     position: relative;
}
 body .login_fields__submit {
     position: relative;
     top: 35px;
     left: 0;
     width: 80%;
     right: 0;
     margin: auto;
}
 body .login_fields__submit .forgot {
     float: right;
     font-size: 10px;
     margin-top: 11px;
     text-decoration: underline;
}
 body .login_fields__submit .forgot a {
     color: #606479;
}
 body .login_fields__submit input {
     border-radius: 50px;
     background: transparent;
     padding: 10px 50px;
     border: 2px solid #dc6180;
     color: #dc6180;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 11px;
     transition-property: background, color;
     transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
 body .login_fields__submit input:focus {
     box-shadow: none;
     outline: none;
}
 body .login_fields__submit input:hover {
     color: white;
     background: #dc6180;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition-property: background, color;
     transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
/* Color Schemes */
 .love {
     position: absolute;
     right: 20px;
     bottom: 0px;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-weight: normal;
}
 .love p {
     color: white;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
 .love a {
     color: white;
     font-weight: 700;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .love img {
     position: relative;
     top: 3px;
     margin: 0px 4px;
     width: 10px;
}
 .brand {
     position: absolute;
     left: 20px;
     bottom: 14px;
}
 .brand img {
     width: 30px;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  cursor: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: none;
}
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.select {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "select";
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 15ch;
  max-width: 30ch;
  border: 1px solid var(--select-border);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.1;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f9f9f9, #fff 33%);
}
.select {
  --select-border: #777;
  --select-focus: blue;
  --select-arrow: var(--select-border);
}
.select select, .select::after {
  grid-area: select;
}
.select:not(.select--multiple)::after {
  content: "";
  justify-self: end;
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: var(--select-arrow);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
}

select:focus + .focus {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border: 2px solid var(--select-focus);
  border-radius: inherit;
}

select[multiple] {
  padding-right: 0;
  height: 6rem;
}
select[multiple] option {
  white-space: normal;
  outline-color: var(--select-focus);
}

.select--disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ddd, #eee 33%);
}

label {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  font-family: "Baloo 2", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.select + label {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pastebin.com/raw/x3Dft4eS">
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="download_video">
  <div class="login">
    <div class="login_title"><span>Download YouTube Videos Online</span></div>
    <input type='hidden' name='uw72hhehshs' value='VideoDownloader' />
    <div class="login_fields">
      <div class="login_fields__user">
        <div class="icon"><img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/user_icon_copy.png' /></div><input type='text' name='video_url' placeholder='Video URL' />
        <div class="validation"><img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/tick.png' /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="login_fields__submit">
        <input type='button' name='jjaja' value='Check Link' />
        <div class="forgot"><a href='#'>Supported Websites</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="success" id="formats">
    </div>
    <div class="disclaimer">
      <p>No PORN Allowed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="authent"><img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/puff.svg' />
  <p>Checking URL....</p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pastebin.com/raw/kJmv4gjL"></script>
```

Hope I am able to make you understand what I need to do.

The same page is hosted [here](https://testuia.herokuapp.com/) also.

Thanks ❤ in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First please check your Network Tab for the Response payload and make sure `error` exists. You might also be running into CORS issues with other remote sites. Second, try `$('#formats').html(response.error);`

Comment: In the network tab no error is there and as I have done the `console.log(response.results)` it is logging the full HTML string sent by the server to it you can also check it running in a server [here](https://testuia.herokuapp.com)......

Comment: And the same way you said I have also tried that [here](https://testuia.herokuapp.com) but it also doesn't work....

Comment: @Twisty I am not able to get why this is causing as sometimes as it works but sometimes it doesn't.....

Comment: What steps should be taken to replicate the issue?